# Can I get HREF values using Mechanize which are not within the form?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I have similar  HTML in one of my pages (with form name):

```
<form name="test">
<td> <A HREF="http://www.edu/st/file.html">bla bla</A> </td>
<td> <A HREF="http://www.mac/spgm/file.html">boo bla</A> </td>
<td> <A HREF="http://www.dom/st/file.html">foo</A> </td>
</form>
```

Another page without form name:

```
<td> <A HREF="http://www.edu/st/file.html">bla bla</A> </td>
<td> <A HREF="http://www.mac/spgm/file.html">boo bla</A> </td>
<td> <A HREF="http://www.dom/st/file.html">foo</A> </td>
```

In both cases I have the values `bla bla`, `boo`, `foo`. Using the values, can I get the respective `href` values using Mechanize?

Comment: It's a good idea to make sure the sample HTML you post is valid because that can make a big difference in how the target nodes are accessed. What you gave in the first example isn't valid.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes,I just tried to give here format,that I have. as the full html is too big.

Comment: Then you strip it down to the essentials needed to replicate the problem, while keeping it valid.

Comment: @theTinMan from your experience I would expect that you can give me a better soluntion in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454058/getting-error-getaddrinfo-no-such-host-is-known-socke-terror-with-mechaniz/14454623#comment20132420_14454623). may I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just take the `href` attribute from the link:

```
m = Mechanize.new
page = m.get("yourpage")
page.link_with(:text => "bla bla").href #=> "http://www.edu/st/file.html"
```

Comment: `+1` to you! :) I am overwhelmed.

Comment: Could you please help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467164/is-it-possible-to-find-the-td-td-text-when-any-of-the-td-td-value/14467236#comment20152656_144672360)

Answer (score 2):

You could try iterating over all of the links on the page and checking if the text is the same.

```
doc.xpath('//a[@href]').each do |link|
  if link.text.strip == "bla bla"
    # Your code here.
end
```

Comment: `+1` to you! :) I am overwhelmed.