# Is it possible to find the <td> .. </td> text, when any of the <td>..</td> value is known?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I have an webpage which has the similar kind of `html` format as below:

```
<form name="test">

<td> .... </td>
  .
  .
  .
<td> <A HREF="http://www.edu/st/file.html">alo</A> </td>
<td> <A HREF="http://www.dom/st/file.html">foo</A> </td>
<td> bla bla </td>

</form>
```

Now, I know only the value `bla bla`, base on the value can we track or find the `3rd last`  .. value(which is here `alo`)? I can track those,with the help of `HREF` values,but the `HREF` values are not fixed always, they can be anything anytime.

Comment: Again, your HTML isn't real helpful. Is there a `<tr>` wrapping each `<td>` or are they all embedded within one `<tr>`? Where are the `<table>` opening and closing tags? There are innumerable questions on SO for parsing HTML tables using Nokogiri.

Comment: @theTinMan All are in one <tr>. But I am not using `nokogiri` instead using `mechanize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting every `<td>` from an HTML document is easy, but it's not a foolproof way to navigate the DOM. However, given the limitations of the sample HTML, here's a solution. I doubt it'll work in a real-world situation though.

Mechanize uses Nokogiri internally for its heavy lifting so doing `require 'nokogiri'` isn't necessary if you've already required Mechanize.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<td> <A HREF="http://www.edu/st/file.html">alo</A> </td>
<td> <A HREF="http://www.dom/st/file.html">foo</A> </td>
<td> bla bla </td>
EOT

doc.search('td')[-3].at('a')['href']
=> "http://www.edu/st/file.html"
```

How to get the Nokogiri document from the Mechanize "agent" is left as an exercise for the user.

Comment: Thank you sir to help me here. But I am using mechanize.So would like to know how i use mechanize `page` or `form` object with `nokogiri`?

Comment: You'll need to search for the answer. The Nokogiri docs don't mention anything about Mechanize. And, as @lichtamberg and I said, Mechanize uses Nokogiri, so you *ARE* using Nokogiri and have it available to you.

Comment: I found out which is `doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(agent.current_page().body)` :)

Comment: Wrong, because you don't need to reparse anything. It's already a Nokogiri document when Mechanize hands it off. Search on Stack Overflow. There are many questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

see http://nokogiri.org/

it helps you to parse html code and then find the elements via selectors

Comment: I am using `mechanize`. So I couldn't use `nokogiri`. I am looking for a `mechanize` solution for the same.

Comment: mechanize is using nokogiri for parsing.. so you can take these selectors

Comment: Okay! I am not that much aware of nokogiri! can you help me to give a sample code with my example?

Comment: How would I use `mechanize` page or form object with `nokogiri`?

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU Use `page.parser` to get the nokogiri parser, then manipulate it with all nokogiri functions. It is the same as `Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)`.